# Spring MVC - Index of out of bounds in property path 'array[0]' on form post with list binding

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I am running into a very confusing problem. I'm trying to bind a list (of filters) to a form. Displaying the items from the list works fine, but posting them gives me an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

For context: this is what my Controller method. Models and forms look like:

**Controller Method**

```
    @PostMapping("/filter")
    public String FilterLoggingAnalysis(@ModelAttribute LoggingAnalysisFilteringForm filterForm, Model model) {
        ...
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

**Wrapper (classes that inherit this object dont have their own get/setters)**

```
public abstract class AbstractAnalysisFilteringForm<T,G> {
    private List<G> filters;
    
    public AbstractAnalysisFilteringForm() {
    }
    
    public AbstractAnalysisFilteringForm(AbstractAnalysisFilteringForm<T, G> abstractAnalysisFilteringForm) {
        this.filters = abstractAnalysisFilteringForm.getFilters();
    }
        
    public List<G> getFilters() {
        return filters;
    }

    public void setFilters(List<G> filters) {
        this.filters = filters;
    }
    
    public void addFilter(G filter) {
        this.filters.add(filter);
    }
}
```

**Object to display/edit (classes that inherit this object dont have their own get/setters)**

```
public abstract class AbstractFilter<T> {
    private String value;   
    private long id;
    
    public AbstractFilter(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public AbstractFilter() {
    }
    
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**Form**

```
            <form action="#" th:action="@{/filter}" th:object="${filterForm}" method="post">
                <div th:each="loggingFilter, iStat : *{filters}" class="form-group">
                    <label>Filter by text</label>
                    <input th:field="*{filters[__${iStat.index}__].value}" class="form-control" placeholder="Example input" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" th:value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Am I missing something? I have used form binding successfully before with the use of a Wrapper class, but not with a list of objects. I've looked at the Spring docs but no solution seems to be working

Comment: Maybe I'm just ignorant about the details re what you are trying to do but I notice your two working classes are abstract.  Abstract classes can't be instantiated but must be extended in order to be of any use.  Is that an issue here?  Just wondering.

Comment: I am passing objects to my view that inherit this abstract class, my @GetMapping and thymeleaf show the data correctly. Posting the form just gives me the outOfBoundsException